# Make the image in gridView darker when clicking, at same time it will open another activity

Tags: android, gridview

I want to add some imageViews into a gridView, and when I click the imageView, it will jump to a big picture viewer activity. And when my finger touched the imageView, the view will become darker.

Here is my way to realize it.

```
gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter());

gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                JumpToImageViewer(imageUrlsFinal, position);
            }
        });
```

In the ImageAdapter， I setOnTouchListener on the ImageView. And rewrite the OnTouch method.
When I get ACTION_DOWN, I make the imageView darker, and when get ACTION_UP,make it be normal. And then return false.

There are the problems:
1, When I return false in onTouch method, and then I click the imageView, and JumpToImageViewer are executed well, but the imageView just go darker, but cannot be back.

2, When I use return true in OnTouch, the imageView can change the color successful. But the JumpToImageViewer are not be ran.

And I know, maybe using return false will make listener change from imageview to its father gridview, and that's why it's not effective.

But I cannot find a solution to deal with this situation. How can I realize that click the imageView in GridView will jump to another Activity. And the same time the imageView will change its color.

Thank you very much.

Comment: can you please post your adapter code ?

Comment: I have post my code, please help me check it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my ImageAdaper.

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Activity mActivity;
private List<String> mImageUrls;
private int mImageWidth;

public ImageAdapter(Activity activity, List<String> imageUrls, int imageWidth) {
    this.mActivity = activity;
    this.mImageUrls = imageUrls;
    this.mImageWidth = imageWidth;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mImageUrls.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return mImageUrls.get(i);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return i;
}

@Override
public View getView(int pos, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    final ImageView imageView;
    if (null == view) {
        imageView = new ImageView(mActivity);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(mImageWidth, mImageWidth));
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView)view;
    }

    String imageUrl = mImageUrls.get(pos);

    ImageCacheManager.getInstance().getImageLoader().get(imageUrl, ImageLoader.getImageListener(imageView, R.drawable.logologo, R.drawable.logologo));

    AnimationUtils.addTouchColorChange(imageView, true);

    return imageView;
}
}



public class AnimationUtils {
/**
 * 给试图添加点击效果,让背景变深 
 * */
public static void addTouchColorChange(View view, boolean isClick){
    view.setOnTouchListener( VIEW_TOUCH_DARK ) ;

    if(!isClick){
        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            }
        });
    }
}

/**
 * 给试图添加点击效果,让背景变淡
 * */
public static void addTouchLight(View view , boolean isClick){
    view.setOnTouchListener( VIEW_TOUCH_LIGHT ) ;

    if(!isClick){
        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            }
        });
    }
}


/**
 * 让控件点击时，颜色变深 
 * */
public static final OnTouchListener VIEW_TOUCH_DARK = new OnTouchListener() {
    /*设定透明值，越小透明度越大*/
    public int transparent_level = 150;

    public final float[] DARKER = new float[] { 1, 0, 0, 0, -50, 0, 1,
        0, 0, -50, 0, 0, 1, 0, -50, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 };
    public final float[] RESTORE = new float[] { 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 };
    public final float[] TRANSPARENT = new float[] { 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                                                     0, 1, 0, 0, 0,
                                                     0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
                                                     0, 0, 0, 1, transparent_level - 255
    };
    int r, g, b;

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            if(v instanceof ImageView){
                ImageView iv = (ImageView) v;
                iv.setColorFilter(new ColorMatrixColorFilter(DARKER)) ;
            } else if (v instanceof TextView){
                TextView tv = (TextView) v;
                String tvColor = Integer.toHexString(tv.getCurrentTextColor());
                b = Integer.parseInt(tvColor.substring(6, 8), 16);
                g = Integer.parseInt(tvColor.substring(4, 6), 16);
                r = Integer.parseInt(tvColor.substring(2, 4), 16);
                tv.setTextColor(Color.argb(transparent_level, r, g, b));
                Drawable[] drawables = tv.getCompoundDrawables();
                if(null != drawables[0]) {
                    drawables[0].setColorFilter(new ColorMatrixColorFilter(TRANSPARENT));
                }
            } else{
                v.getBackground().setColorFilter( new ColorMatrixColorFilter(DARKER) );
                v.setBackgroundDrawable(v.getBackground());
            }
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            if(v instanceof ImageView){
                ImageView iv = (ImageView) v;
                iv.setColorFilter( new ColorMatrixColorFilter(RESTORE) ) ;
            } else if (v instanceof TextView){
                TextView tv = (TextView) v;
                tv.setTextColor(Color.argb(255, r, g, b));
                Drawable[] drawables = tv.getCompoundDrawables();
                if(null != drawables[0]) {
                    drawables[0].setColorFilter(new ColorMatrixColorFilter(RESTORE));
                }
            } else{
                v.getBackground().setColorFilter(
                    new ColorMatrixColorFilter(RESTORE));
                v.setBackgroundDrawable(v.getBackground());
            }
            break;
        default:
            if(v instanceof ImageView){
                ImageView iv = (ImageView) v;
                iv.setColorFilter( new ColorMatrixColorFilter(RESTORE)) ;
            }
            break;
        }
        return false;
    }
};
}
```